# Filtering multiple, specific columns for multiple time ranges

Tags: r, time-series, subset, multiple-columns

I'm QCing data and for several tanks/data_types there are faulty data that need to be removed, spanning multiple time ranges. The data_types, tanks and time ranges that contain faulty data have been reported in a separate data frame, a snippet of which is contained in this QC_table:

```
structure(list(trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), data_type = c("Temp", 
"pH", "pH", "pH", "Temp", "Temp"), tank = c("29", "40", "40", 
"40", "13", "29"), date_time_start = c("2021-03-31 8:30", "2021-03-31 7:50", 
"2021-03-31 10:25", "2021-03-31 17:05", "2021-04-07 10:25", "2021-04-08 10:30"
), date_time_end = c("2021-03-31 18:00", "2021-03-31 8:15", "2021-03-31 10:40", 
"2021-03-31 17:30", "2021-04-07 17:20", "2021-04-10 18:25"), 
    to.be.removed = c("yes ", "yes ", "yes ", "yes ", "yes ", 
    "yes "), reason = c("calibration error", "faulty probe", 
    "faulty probe", "faulty probe", "calibration error", "faulty probe"
    ), data_type_tank = c("WalchemTempTank29", "pH_Tank40", "pH_Tank40", 
    "pH_Tank40", "WalchemTempTank13", "WalchemTempTank29")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are additional trials and tanks to this. My approach to this was to create a new dataframe with all the data that needs to be removed (based on data_type_tank and date_time_start/end columns in the QC table), and then remove that data frame from the original dataframe. I don't know if this is the most logical, but I wouldn't know how I would be able to remove the data from the original dataframe.

I construct a new dataframe using:

```
new_dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
select(c(Measurement.time, Trial, contains(urchin_temp_pH_QC$data_type_tank))) %>% head(10)

structure(list(Measurement.time = c("2021-03-30 11:00", "2021-03-30 11:05", 
"2021-03-30 11:10", "2021-03-30 11:15", "2021-03-30 11:20", "2021-03-30 11:25", 
"2021-03-30 11:30", "2021-03-30 11:35", "2021-03-30 11:40", "2021-03-30 11:45"
), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WalchemTempTank29_Avg = c("18.8", 
"18.67", "18.58", "18.48", "18.38", "18.29", "18.2", "18.12", 
"18.03", "18"), WalchemTempTank29_Std = c("0.037", "0.025", "0.032", 
"0.029", "0.017", "0.018", "0.026", "0.025", "0.024", "0.023"
), pH_Tank40_Avg = c("7.859", "7.863", "7.868", "7.866", "7.863", 
"7.864", "7.865", "7.867", "7.869", "7.87"), pH_Tank40_Std = c("0.007", 
"0.006", "0.002", "0.001", "0.002", "0.001", "0.002", "0.001", 
"0.002", "0.004"), WalchemTempTank13_Avg = c("10.26", "10.22", 
"10.21", "10.24", "10.27", "10.3", "10.32", "10.34", "10.37", 
"10.4"), WalchemTempTank13_Std = c("0.01", "0.013", "0.005", 
"0.01", "0.007", "0.006", "0.006", "0.008", "0.008", "0.005")), row.names = 4:13, class = "data.frame")
```

However now, based on the QC table there are some rows (date/time) that I need to remove or subset for, but only for specific columns (ie. those columns that contain the data_type_tank). I think I can do this manually, using the code below, and then binding or joining columns/rows where needed, but this seems like an arduous process.

```
subset_row_1_QC_table <-  dataframe %>% select(Measurement.time, contains("WalchemTempTank29")) %>% 
subset(Measurement.time >= as.POSIXct("2021-03-31 08:30") & Measurement.time <= as.POSIXct("2021-03-31 18:00"))
```

Is there any way to automate this process, removing or subsetting column-specific rows, based on columns from a different data frame? I think ideally my dataframe would look something like an expanded version of eg:

| Measurement.time | Trial | WaterTempTank29_Avg | WaterTempTank29_Std | pH_Tank40_Avg | pH_Tank40_Std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-31 08:30 | 1 | 18.8 | 0.037 | NA | NA |
| [all 5-min intervals] |  |  |  | NA | NA |
| 2021-03-31 18:00 | 1 | 18.36 | 0.023 | NA | NA |
| 2021-03-31 07:50 | 1 | NA | NA | 7.854 | 0.001 |
| [all 5-min intervals] | 1 | NA | NA | 7.88 | 0.001 |
| 2021-03-31 08:15 | 1 | NA | NA | 7.84 | 0.001 |
| 2021-03-31 10:25 | 1 | NA | NA | 7.881 | 0.001 |
| [all 5-min intervals] | 1 | NA | NA | 7.804 | 0.001 |
| 2021-03-31 10:40 | 1 | NA | NA | 7.881 | 0 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I hope I've been able to explain properly my problem, first-time user of StackOverflow.

Cheers,

edit: Thanks r2evans & GuedesBF -- hope this is now better/fixed.

Comment: please provide code for the data, not links. use `dput(data)`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this.

1. Prepare data for variables `CF` and `df`

```
CF = structure(list(trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L), data_type = c("Temp", "pH", 
 "pH"), tank = c("29", "40", "40"), date_time_start = structure(c(1617204600, 
 1617202200, 1617211500), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
 )), date_time_end = structure(c(1617238800, 1617203700, 1617212400
 ), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), to.be.removed = c("yes ", 
 "yes ", "yes "), reason = c("calibration error", "faulty probe", 
 "faulty probe"), data_type_tank = c("WalchemTempTank29", "pH_Tank40", 
 "pH_Tank40")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(
 data_type = c("pH", "Temp"), tank = c("40", "29"), .rows = structure(list(
 2:3, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df = structure(list(Measurement.time = c("2021-03-30 11:00", "2021-03-30 11:05", 
 "2021-03-30 11:10", "2021-03-30 11:15", "2021-03-31 18:30", "2021-03-30 11:25", 
 "2021-03-30 11:30", "2021-03-30 11:35", "2021-03-31 17:00", "2021-03-31 19:28"
), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WalchemTempTank29_Avg = c("18.8", 
 "18.67", "18.58", "18.48", "18.38", "18.29", "18.2", "18.12", 
 "18.03", "18"), WalchemTempTank29_Std = c("0.037", "0.025", "0.032", 
 "0.029", "0.017", "0.018", "0.026", "0.025", "0.024", "0.023"
 ), pH_Tank40_Avg = c("7.859", "7.863", "7.868", "7.866", "7.863", 
 "7.864", "7.865", "7.867", "7.869", "7.87"), pH_Tank40_Std = c("0.007", 
 "0.006", "0.002", "0.001", "0.002", "0.001", "0.002", "0.001", 
 "0.002", "0.004"), WalchemTempTank13_Avg = c("10.26", "10.22", 
 "10.21", "10.24", "10.27", "10.3", "10.32", "10.34", "10.37", 
 "10.4"), WalchemTempTank13_Std = c("0.01", "0.013", "0.005", 
 "0.01", "0.007", "0.006", "0.006", "0.008", "0.008", "0.005")), row.names = 4:13, class = "data.frame")
```

Note, I changed some data in the variable `Measurement.time` to include the events in the `CF` table.

2. Prepare separate tables `CFTemp` and `CFpH`

```
CFTemp = CF %>% ungroup() %>% 
  filter(data_type == "Temp") %>% 
  mutate(Temp = "Temp",
         Temp_start = date_time_start,
         Temp_end = date_time_end) %>% 
  select(Temp, Temp_start, Temp_end)

CFpH = CF %>% ungroup() %>% 
  filter(data_type == "pH") %>% 
  mutate(pH = "pH",
        pH_start = date_time_start,
        pH_end = date_time_end) %>% 
  select(pH, pH_start, pH_end)
```

3. Prepare two functions returning vectors with binary values and for which indices data should be removed.

```
fTemp = function(df) CFTemp %>% left_join(df, by="Temp") %>%
  mutate(TempRm = Measurement.time>=Temp_start & Measurement.time<=Temp_end) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(TempRm = any(TempRm)) %>%
  pull(TempRm)

fpH = function(df) CFpH %>% left_join(df, by="pH") %>%
  mutate(pHRm = Measurement.time>=pH_start & Measurement.time<=pH_end) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(pHRm = any(pHRm)) %>%
  pull(pHRm)
```

4. Convert the data frame

```
df1 = df %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Measurement.time = as.POSIXct(Measurement.time),
         ID = 1:nrow(.),
         Temp = "Temp",
         pH = "pH") %>%
  mutate( 
    TmpRm = fTemp(.),
    pHRm = fpH(.)
  ) %>%
  mutate( 
    WalchemTempTank29_Avg = ifelse(TmpRm, NA, WalchemTempTank29_Avg),
    WalchemTempTank29_Std = ifelse(TmpRm, NA, WalchemTempTank29_Std),
    WalchemTempTank13_Avg = ifelse(TmpRm, NA, WalchemTempTank13_Avg),
    WalchemTempTank13_Std = ifelse(TmpRm, NA, WalchemTempTank13_Std),
    pH_Tank40_Avg = ifelse(pHRm, NA, pH_Tank40_Avg),
    pH_Tank40_Std = ifelse(pHRm, NA, pH_Tank40_Std),
  ) %>%
  select(Measurement.time:WalchemTempTank13_Std)

df1
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   Measurement.time    Trial WalchemTempTank29_Avg WalchemTempTank29_Std pH_Tank40_Avg pH_Tank40_Std WalchemTempTank13_Avg WalchemTempTank13_Std
   <dttm>              <int> <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>         <chr>                 <chr>                
 1 2021-03-30 11:00:00     1 18.8                  0.037                 7.859         0.007         10.26                 0.01                 
 2 2021-03-30 11:05:00     1 18.67                 0.025                 7.863         0.006         10.22                 0.013                
 3 2021-03-30 11:10:00     1 18.58                 0.032                 7.868         0.002         10.21                 0.005                
 4 2021-03-30 11:15:00     1 18.48                 0.029                 7.866         0.001         10.24                 0.01                 
 5 2021-03-31 18:30:00     1 NA                    NA                    7.863         0.002         NA                    NA                   
 6 2021-03-30 11:25:00     1 18.29                 0.018                 7.864         0.001         10.3                  0.006                
 7 2021-03-30 11:30:00     1 18.2                  0.026                 7.865         0.002         10.32                 0.006                
 8 2021-03-30 11:35:00     1 18.12                 0.025                 7.867         0.001         10.34                 0.008                
 9 2021-03-31 17:00:00     1 18.03                 0.024                 NA            NA            10.37                 0.008                
10 2021-03-31 19:28:00     1 NA                    NA                    NA            NA            NA                    NA
```

And that's all.

**Update 1**

```
library(tidyverse)

CFTemp = CF %>% ungroup() %>%
  filter(data_type == "Temp") %>%
  mutate(Temp = "Temp",
         Temp_start = date_time_start,
         Temp_end = date_time_end) %>%
  select(Temp, tank, Temp_start, Temp_end)

CFpH = CF %>% ungroup() %>%
  filter(data_type == "pH") %>%
  mutate(pH = "pH",
        pH_start = date_time_start,
        pH_end = date_time_end) %>%
  select(pH, pH_start, pH_end)

fTemp = function(df, Tank){ 
  out = CFTemp %>% filter(tank==Tank) %>% 
  left_join(df, by="Temp") %>%
  mutate(TempRm = Measurement.time>=Temp_start & Measurement.time<=Temp_end) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(TempRm = any(TempRm)) %>%
  pull(TempRm)
  if(length(out)==0) FALSE else out
}

fpH = function(df) CFpH %>% left_join(df, by="pH") %>%
  mutate(pHRm = Measurement.time>=pH_start & Measurement.time<=pH_end) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(pHRm = any(pHRm)) %>%
  pull(pHRm)

df1 = df %>% as_tibble() %>% #Step 1
  mutate(Measurement.time = as.POSIXct(Measurement.time),
         ID = 1:nrow(.),
         Temp = "Temp",
         pH = "pH") %>%
  mutate( #Step 2
    TmpRm29 = fTemp(., 29),
    TmpRm13 = fTemp(., 13),
    pHRm = fpH(.)
  ) %>%
  mutate( #Step 3
    WalchemTempTank29_Avg = ifelse(TmpRm29, NA, WalchemTempTank29_Avg),
    WalchemTempTank29_Std = ifelse(TmpRm29, NA, WalchemTempTank29_Std),
    WalchemTempTank13_Avg = ifelse(TmpRm13, NA, WalchemTempTank13_Avg),
    WalchemTempTank13_Std = ifelse(TmpRm13, NA, WalchemTempTank13_Std),
    pH_Tank40_Avg = ifelse(pHRm, NA, pH_Tank40_Avg),
    pH_Tank40_Std = ifelse(pHRm, NA, pH_Tank40_Std),
  ) %>%
  select(Measurement.time:WalchemTempTank13_Std)

df1
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   Measurement.time    Trial WalchemTempTank29_Avg WalchemTempTank29_Std pH_Tank40_Avg pH_Tank40_Std WalchemTempTank13_Avg WalchemTempTank13_Std
   <dttm>              <int> <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>         <chr>                 <chr>                
 1 2021-03-30 11:00:00     1 18.8                  0.037                 7.859         0.007         10.26                 0.01                 
 2 2021-03-30 11:05:00     1 18.67                 0.025                 7.863         0.006         10.22                 0.013                
 3 2021-03-30 11:10:00     1 18.58                 0.032                 7.868         0.002         10.21                 0.005                
 4 2021-03-30 11:15:00     1 18.48                 0.029                 7.866         0.001         10.24                 0.01                 
 5 2021-03-31 18:30:00     1 NA                    NA                    7.863         0.002         10.27                 0.007                
 6 2021-03-30 11:25:00     1 18.29                 0.018                 7.864         0.001         10.3                  0.006                
 7 2021-03-30 11:30:00     1 18.2                  0.026                 7.865         0.002         10.32                 0.006                
 8 2021-03-30 11:35:00     1 18.12                 0.025                 7.867         0.001         10.34                 0.008                
 9 2021-03-31 17:00:00     1 18.03                 0.024                 NA            NA            10.37                 0.008                
10 2021-03-31 19:28:00     1 NA                    NA                    NA            NA            10.4                  0.005
```

Comment: Thank you @ Marek! This helps a lot!! It seems to succesfully remove the faulty measurements associated to the pH. For some reason however it seems to cluster the temperature measurements that need to be removed from original dataframe (i.e. Temp measurements from both Tank 29 and 13 are removed for a specific time range, even though it should only apply to a specific tank #). Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: See now. I improved the code a bit. However, this will only work for `tank` 29 and 13. If you have different values in your data, you will have to correct the code.

P.S.
You gave us a little bit of data. You should have a more representative example.

Comment: Thank you Marek, I apologize that the example wasn't as representative as it should be. I will update my initial post to include the faulty data from Tank 13 that would need to be removed. The table might be extended as we're still working through all the data. While the correct pH data is removed, I'm afraid I still don't seem to be able to remove the correct temperature measurements in the specific time ranges... No error message is given, just the data is not replaced with NA.

Comment: When I manually fill in the function, ie. 

`out = CFTemp %>% filter(tank==29) %>%
  left_join(df, by="Temp") %>%
  mutate(TempRm = Measurement.time >= Temp_start & Measurement.time <= Temp_end) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(TempRm = any(TempRm)) %>%
  pull(TempRm)
  ifelse(length(out)==0, FALSE, out)
  }` 

It seems to work (I get a list of logical values), but if I do `fTemp(df, 29)` I get FALSE as output. Is there something glaringly obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I did have a small mistake. Instead `ifelse (length (out) == 0, FALSE, out)` should be `if (length (out) == 0) FALSE else out`. I have already corrected it in response. Everything should work fine now. Please check it with all the data and let me know how it works.

Comment: This seems to work great, thank you so much Marek!!